# How to pass a parameter in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a code in `WindowAfterLogin.xaml`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="In_Time" Foreground="#FF55534F" 
           FontSize="71.312" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" 
           Height="79.45" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" 
           Canvas.Left="2.724" LineHeight="71.312" 
           TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Canvas.Top="69.985" Width="231.581" Text="09:00" />
```

And then I want to change the value of that `TextBlock` in `WindowAfterLogin.xaml.cs`, so I've done this :

```
MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
WindowAfterLogin objAfterLogin = new WindowAfterLogin();                
objMainWindow.Show();
objAfterLogin.In_Time.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
this.Close();
```

But, when I press F5 button (Compile), it didn't change. Where is the problem here?

Comment: try `this.In_time.Text` instead

Comment: where should i put that code? because it was error everywhere..

Comment: @GrantWinney it came from this code:
WindowAfterLogin objAfterLogin = new WindowAfterLogin();

Comment: aahh, I understand @safetyOtter. But still, it didn't change.

Comment: On what event are you changing the text? Please show us the code for that event.

Comment: @GrantWinney sorry, I'm a newbie here. So I don't know what to do. But this is the codes that I have, so I think with these codes, the value of that textblock will change.

Comment: @jomsk1e my comment same as above

Comment: You are changing the value.  you're just not showing the window that you're changing it it.  Before `this.Close();` put it `objAfterLogin.Show()`

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a separate instance of `WindowAfterLogin` ? If you want to do that, you will have to `Show()` the new instance. Try this:

```
    WindowAfterLogin objAfterLogin = new WindowAfterLogin();                
    objAfterLoginShow();
    objAfterLogin.In_Time.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
    //Close(); //Close any other window that needs to be closed..
```

If you wanted the `In_Time.Text` to change for the current instance, (assuming that has been showed or is visible currrently), you can try this perhaps in the constructor or your method that Initializes the `WindowAfterLogin` :

```
In_Time.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simplification to ***bit*** answer, try to write something like this instead of your code

```
MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
objMainWindow.Show();
In_Time.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
this.Close(); //Not sure if You need it. Try to comment this line to be able to notice textblock text changes
```

Also I think You need

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm")
```

instead of

```
DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString()
```